# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka : How to access recordMetadata of kafka headers after producing a message to a kafka topic

Tags: spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I want get the offset and partition information after i produce a message to kafka topic.
I read through spring cloud stream kafka binding document and found that that can be achieved by fecthing RECORD_METADATA kafka header.

From Spring documentation: (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-producer-properties)

recordMetadataChannel
The bean name of a MessageChannel to which successful send results should be sent; the bean must exist in the application context. The message sent to the channel is the sent message (after conversion, if any) with an additional header KafkaHeaders.RECORD_METADATA. The header contains a RecordMetadata object provided by the Kafka client; it includes the partition and offset where the record was written in the topic.

ResultMetadata meta = sendResultMsg.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RECORD_METADATA, RecordMetadata.class)

---

I have configured my output topic bean name as message channel in the property file
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.acknowledgement-out.producer.record-metadata-channel = acknowledgement-out

my customized interface and producer class as below:

```java
public interface OutputAcknowledgement {    

    @Output("acknowledgement-out")
    MessageChannel output();

}
```

Producer class:

```java
@EnableBinding(OutputAcknowledgement.class)
public class AcknowledgementProducer {
   

    @Autowired
    OutputAcknowledgement outputAcknowledgement;

    public Boolean produce(Acknowledgement acknowledgement) {
        Message msg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(acknowledgement).build();

        boolean val = outputAcknowledgement.output().send(msg);

        RecordMetadata recordMetadata = msg.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RECORD_METADATA, RecordMetadata.class);
```

Getting null for recordMetadata.

Please suggest whether my approach is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting null because it doesn't exist in that message object at the time you're accessing it. According to the docs the metadata is only provided after successful publish. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66436499/get-partition-and-offset-number-in-which-kafka-message-is-being-processed-using/66442969#66442969) on how to get record metadata by providing a handler/consumer for the record metadata channel.