# Accessing RecordMetadata in spring-cloud-stream-kafka binder: how to specify recordMetadataChannel

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am writing a Kafka Producer and Consumer using spring cloud stream Kafka binder. I want access to the following information in both the producer and consumer

a) Topic
b) Partition
b) Offset

I did check the documentation, and am not really able to find where to get this is done. All I see in the documentation is to specify a `recordMetadataChannel` as part of the producer/ consumer configuration. Would someone point me to any samples of how exactly this is done?

Answer (score 0):

The `RecordMetadata` in the message headers sent to that channel contains that information.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66436499/get-partition-and-offset-number-in-which-kafka-message-is-being-processed-using/66442969#66442969).