# Spring cloud stream 4.x metadatachannel

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

want to get the output channel name after message is published to the destination.

metadata channel is not available in 4.x
 `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.myBinding.producer.**record-metadata-channel**`

Spring cloud stream : 4.0.1

binder type : Kafka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me with version `4.0.1`. When the supplier is invoked and the message is published to the Kafka topic, the handler method on the record metadata channel is called. I can see the sent message in the output. What is not working in your application?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So75681179Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So75681179Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Supplier<Message<String>> supplier() {
        return () -> MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo").setHeader(KafkaHeaders.KEY, "my-foo".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel fooRecordChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow() {
        return f -> f.channel("fooRecordChannel")
                .handle((payload, messageHeaders) -> {
                    System.out.println("Sent message: " + new String((byte[]) payload));
                    return payload;
                });
    }
}
```

and the configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: supplier
    stream:
      kafka:
        bindings:
          supplier-out-0:
            producer:
              recordMetadataChannel: fooRecordChannel
```

Comment: Thanks. worked .

It is missing in the latest documentation 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html

Hence was referring the  answer in SO 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66436499/get-partition-and-offset-number-in-which-kafka-message-is-being-processed-using/66442969#66442969
didnt work 

We have usecase to do post processing audit and need to extract the outbound channel name(destination) in such case whether "recordMetadataChannel" is right recommendation ?