# using record-metadata-channel in spring cloud stream kaffka-binder

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Looking for help to capture the Partition and offset of the message being sent over Kafka in spring cloud stream function flows with binders and bindings. Seems something is wrong with the configuration I am unable to use metachannel though followed the config given here
[Get Partition and Offset number in which kafka message is being processed using StreamBridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66436499/get-partition-and-offset-number-in-which-kafka-message-is-being-processed-using/66442969#66442969)
Appreciate any help here in cloud stream 4.0.2 version

tried
[Get Partition and Offset number in which kafka message is being processed using StreamBridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66436499/get-partition-and-offset-number-in-which-kafka-message-is-being-processed-using/66442969#66442969)

Comment: Did you look at this section in the ref docs? https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_keeping_track_of_successful_sending_of_records_producing_in_kafka